# When I change sdk version ,I am encountering Theme.Dialog error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

I'm trying to install Firebase Crashlytics for my android app. All versions of Firebase Crashlytics accept 16 as a minimum SDK. `minSdkVersion` 14 available in my application. When I raise the `minSdkVersion` to 16, I get the following error

> C:\Users\Emircan\Desktop\mlxpos\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:2:5-5:13: AAPT: error: resource android:style/android:Theme.Dialog not found.

error line:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@android:style/android:Theme.Dialog</item>
</style>
```

If I setthe `minSdkVersion` 14, I get the following error.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0] C:\Users\Emircan.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cfbe933ef2af918ca181d266a71288ac\firebase-analytics-17.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

How can I fix this ? (The lowest version of crashlytics is 17.0.0, it doesn't accept it either.)

Here is the build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1254'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crash.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28

        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            /* Do not compile these resources in debug mode. Faster build time.
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            crunchPngs false */
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    productFlavors {

    }

    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.YarikSOffice:lingver:1.3.0"

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    implementation files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/acra-4.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.10.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/d2xx.jar')
    // Gprinter library
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gprintersdkv2.1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jcc-bate-0.7.3.jar')
    // Gprinter library finish
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation(name: 'callerlibrary', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'numbertowordsconverter', ext: 'aar')
    // compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    // implementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
    // implementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use `Firebase Crashlytics` you have to upgrade the minimal sdk version to at least 16.
The problem that you encountered when min sdk is set to 16 is caused by wrong theme that does not exist in the newer version (Theme.Dialog). Change it to `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` and it should be fine.